# PHP mailer bulk email one by one

Tags: php, mailer

I am reading emails from a text file and have to send one email at a time. Everything(sender, subject, body) is constant except for receiver. I have my PHP mailer working and the additional code I am using is:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES) {
    if ($_FILES['file']['name'] != "") {
        if (isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['file']['type'] != 'text/plain') {
            echo "<span>File could not be accepted ! Please upload any '*.txt' file.   </span>";
            exit();
        } 

        echo "<center><span id='Content'>Contents of ".$_FILES['file']['name']." File</span></center>"; 
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file = fopen($fileName,"r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
        $string = file_get_contents("$fileName"); // Load text file contents
        $pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
        $output = var_export($matches[0]);

        foreach ($output as $item) {
            echo "$item\n";
            $output = $item;
        }

        print_r($output);
    } else {
        if (isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['file']['type'] == '') {
            echo "<span>Please Choose a file by click on 'Browse' or 'Choose File' button.</span>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i have a text file full of emails i have to read the emails and send it to one by one. The emails which i read from txt files are receiver address. i am not getting how to send email one by one to all address if you have any thought please share it. thank you

Comment: You can do so either by using a loop or save all email addresses in a comma-seperated string and send at once. Can you post your mailer script, so I can take a look at it and perhaps provide a solution.

Comment: there will be no difference between gmail and my php mailer. The problem is if i send with comma separated then each recipient will be able to see the other recipient's email address but if i send one by one then no one will be able to see each other email address

Comment: Since you are sending the same message, use loop

Comment: ok but i have to use different email each time pls explain with a little bit code that will be very convenient.

Comment: Can you add your mailer script, so I can add a little code for sending mail one by one?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8CPeAv2Z

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple recipients to a single message and set the SingleTo to true.

```
$recipient_addresses = array();
....
$message = new \PHPMailer;
$message->SingleTo = true; 
....
foreach($recipient_addresses as $email) $message->addAddress($email);     
....
```

Please not that the the SingleTo is only supported in "mail" and "sendmail" transports, not in "SMTP".

If you use the SMTP transport, just loop the send for each address one-by-one. Just call $message->addAddress one time to pass just one address for each instance of the PHPMailer class, but create multiple instance, one-by-one:

```
1. $message = new \PHPMailer;
2. $message->addAddress($email); 
3. fill other data, but don't set the SingleTo property value, keep it default (false).
4. $message->send();
5. unset($message);
```

Please also be aware of the fact that SingleTo is planned to be deprecated in the release of PHPMailer 6.0, and removed in 7.0.